# Display the text referenced in another cell in Excel otherwise display a different text

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an Excel workbook that contains a number of individual worksheets. The cells on one of the sheets are linked to individual cells on other worksheet in the same workbook. I'm using a direct cell reference that essentially says that whatever value is entered into a particular cell on one sheet also populates cells on the other sheet. I used the (=) function with the cell reference to accomplish this.

The issue I'm running into is that, even when the primary cell is left blank, the cells that populate from that primary cell will display 0, rather than a text that I want to be display like: "No data here" .

I want the subordinate cells to display "No data here" if the primary cell they're linked to are blank.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Use an IF formula.

Comment: I tried to do so, but I  don't know exactly how to link them as being part of a different worksheet.

Comment: `=if(x="","No data here",x)`

Comment: In your question you say: *The cells on one of the sheets are linked to individual cells on other worksheet in the same workbook.* Please show an example of the complete formula you use.

Comment: Hi. I have used this formula: =IF(Control!B3=" ","Off",Control!B3) and it returns 0. While the cell on Control worksheet is empty and it should return Off.

Comment: The reason for the 0 is that you have a space between the double quotes in `...Control!B3=" ",...`. When the cell is empty, the condition is not true, and the dependent cell doesn't show the text `Off` but shows the content of the empty cell as 0. Remove the space and it works as you wish.

Comment: Please take this as a lesson to always copy - paste formulas or other content verbatim into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ! operator to reference cells on other worksheets.

So you can construct the formula like this:

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1="","Source cell is blank",Sheet1!A1)
```

Obviously, replace "Sheet1" with the name of your source data sheet.

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering . I already tried this but unfortunately is not working :(

Comment: @EricM What do you mean with *...is not working*. What happens and what doesn't happen?

Comment: I have used this formula: =IF(Control!B3=" ","Off",Control!B3) and it returns 0. While the cell on Control worksheet is empty and it should return Off.

Comment: @EricM As explained in a comment to your question, you are not testing for an empty cell, but for a cell with a space character. Remove the space and it works just as this answer tells you.